# Simplify jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to check whether either the element clicked or one of its parents is a `svg` tag. I cannot use `closest()` selector as it's too lenient.

What I have now:

```
if (jClicked.is('svg') || jClicked.parent('svg').length > 0) {
```

Is there a way to drop the OR operator from the expression using selectors only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.add()` since `.is()` would perform an `OR` operation over a collection of elements,

```
if(jClicked.add(jClicked.parent()).is('svg'))
```

And i wonder why you are refusing to use .closest() in this context, it would be very efficient for this case.

```
if(jClicked.closest('svg').length)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a jQuery object which contains both `jClicked` and its parent, then we can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if(jClicked.parent().addBack().is('svg'))
```